# How to use Objects as Swift Type Properties

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, static-members

So what I currently have in mind is the following:

```
class MySKScene : SKScene {
    class var background: SKNode {
        return CustomBackgroundNode()
    }

    ...
}
```

I intend to make my game use these kind of scenes, where they all share a common background. My fear is that I am instantiating a new custom background node upon every reference of this background variable throughout my code.

I did some investigating in debug mode and found that the memory address used for this class variable is always different upon every consecutive reference to the variable (Also, I may be debugging wrongly, I'm still starting out in iOS development)

Is there another way to get class variables that use objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence, you're wanting a singleton background node, so use:

```
class MySKScene : SKScene {
    class var background: SKNode {
        struct Static {
            static let node = CustomBackgroundNode()
        }
        return Static.node
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: You'll have to change this slightly if you want to share a single background node in 3 different scene subclasses, in that case just move the code into CustomBackgroundNode as a singleton implementation there.